# Form not taking action

Tags: html, forms

I have a problem with a form. It is not sending any action (page not even refreshing on click). If I copy the form in another document locally it has no problem, all working well, mail message being sent. Here is the code of the form:

```
<form method='post' name='ContactForm' id='contactForm' action='contact_main.php'>
                                <p>Your name:</p>
                                <input type="text" class="input-box" name="user-name" placeholder="Please enter your name.">
                                <p>Email address:</p>
                                <input type="text" class="input-box" name="user-email" placeholder="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p>Subject:</p>
                                <input type="text" class="input-box" name="user-subject" placeholder="Purpose of this message.">
                                <p class="right-message-box">Message:</p>
                                <textarea class="input-box right-message-box message-box" name="user-message" placeholder="Your message."></textarea>
                                <button type='submit' class='myinputbtn' name='submitf' id="submitf">Send your message</button>
                                <div id='message_post'></div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="contact">
                            </form>
```

Clicking the submit button results in... nothing!

Please let me know if I need to edit my question before downrating. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
<input type="submit" ...
```

instead of a button (which is used with Javascript, not for form submitting)